# bootstrap multiselect select all does not appear in the list

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-multiselect

I am trying to add the select all option in [bootstrap multiselect](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/) list I created.

HTML:

```
<select id="taskNameSelect" class="multiselect" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="multiselect-all">Select all</option>
    {{#each taskName}}
    <option value="{{this}}">{{@key}}</option>
    {{/each}}
</select>
```

JS:

```
Cellomat.Views.TaskStatusView = Backbone.View.extend({
    className: 'row-fluid',
    events: {
        'click .level': 'select_log_level'
    },
    initialize: function() {
        this.template = Handlebars.compile($("#taskStatus-template").html());
    },
    render: function() {
        $(this.el).html(this.template({
            taskName: Cellomat.Models.ActionRequests
        }));
        $(".multiselect", this.el).multiselect({
            selectAllText: 'Select all',
            selectAllValue: 'multiselect-all'
        });
        return this;
    },
    select_log_level: function(event) {
        $('.level').removeClass('active');
        $(event.target).addClass('active');
        var ze_level = $(event.target).data('level');

        this.model.set({
            level_name: ze_level
        });
    }
});
```

The output I get is just dropdown list with all the content apart from the select all.
I need the select all.

Comment: What library are you using? This one perhaps? http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/

Comment: yes... this is the library

Comment: Tnx bro... it's working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include `includeSelectAllOption` when instantiating your multiselect. So:

```
$(".multiselect", this.el).multiselect({
    includeSelectAllOption: true
});
```

will provide the `select-all` option.

Comment: I have similar issue. I have two multiselects and for one it works for the other it doesn't...any ideas?